# How to use the http.post() in the Angular 4/5 correctly?

Tags: vb.net, angular, xmlhttprequest, angular5, angular-httpclient

I have a REST web service developed in VB.NET and an MS Access Database along with that. I was trying to take a string value from my Angular app and then insert it into the Database which comprise of only one table as shown below.

[image]

Now I was trying to insert a value SriLanka from the Angular app into the database with the web service method. Although I was able to insert the value but I don't think that I've implemented the http.post() method correct.

Here is my Angular code:

***app.component.ts***

```
import { Component, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { AppStore } from './app.store';
import { AppState } from './app.state';
import { Store } from 'redux';
import * as DummyService from './Dummy.service';
import * as DummyActions from './Dummy.actions';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { OnInit } from '@angular/core/src/metadata/lifecycle_hooks';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  counter: number;
  country: string;
  http$: HttpClient;


  constructor( @Inject(AppStore) private store: Store<AppState>, http$: HttpClient) {
    this.http$ = http$;


  }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.Load(this.store, this.http$, this.country);
  }

  Load(store: Store<AppState>, http$: HttpClient, country: string) {
    store.subscribe(() => this.readState());
    this.readState();
    DummyService.Load(this.store, this.http$, 'SriLanka');
  }
}
```

***Dummy.service.ts***

```
import * as Redux from 'redux';
import { HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import * as Model from './app.state';
import * as Actions from './Dummy.actions';
export const PASS = "PASS";
export const FAIL = "FAIL";
export const OMIT = "OMIT";

export function Load(store: Redux.Store<Model.AppState>, http$: HttpClient, country: string) {
    try {
        http$.get('assets/AppOptions.json',{responseType: "text"}).subscribe(data => {
            try {
                    var oAppOptions:Model.ApplicationOptions = JSON.parse(data);
                    store.getState().oApplicationOptions = oAppOptions;
                    InsertCountryDetails(store, http$, country);
            }catch(e) {
                alert("Unable to parse the AppOptions.json file.");
            }
        }, function (error:HttpErrorResponse) {
            alert("An error occured while reading the AppOption file.");
        });
    } catch (e) {
        throw new Error("DummyService::Load() Exception : " + e);
    }
}
function InsertCountryDetails(store: Redux.Store<Model.AppState>, http$: HttpClient, country: string){ 
    var WebServiceDataJson: string = JSON.stringify(store.getState().WebServiceData);
    var Servicelink: string = store.getState().oApplicationOptions.WebServiceLink;
    let url = Servicelink + "InsertCountryDetails/" + encodeURI(WebServiceDataJson);
    http$.post(url, country).subscribe((res: Response) => {
        console.log(res);
    });
}
```

Here is my DummyWebService.vb code:

```
Imports System.ServiceModel
Imports System.ServiceModel.Web

<ServiceContract()>
Public Interface IDummyWebService

    <OperationContract>
    <WebInvoke(Method:="POST", ResponseFormat:=WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle:=WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, UriTemplate:="InsertCountryDetails/{WebServiceDataJson}/{Country}")>
    Sub InsertCountryDetails(ByVal WebServiceDataJson As String, ByVal Country As String)

End Interface
```

Here is the DummyWebService.svc.vb code:

```
Imports System.Web.Script.Serialization
Imports DynamicJsonParser
Imports DummyWebService.ServerCallBackResult

' NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the context menu to change the class name "Service1" in code, svc and config file together.
' NOTE: In order to launch WCF Test Client for testing this service, please select Service1.svc or Service1.svc.vb at the Solution Explorer and start debugging.
Public Class Service1
    Implements IDummyWebService

    Public Sub New()
    End Sub
Public Sub InsertCountryDetails(ByVal WebServiceDataJson As String, ByVal Country As String) Implements IDummyWebService.InsertCountryDetails
        RequestLog("InsertCountryDetails WebServiceDataJson : " & WebServiceDataJson & ", Country : " & Country)
        Dim callBack As ServerCallBackResult = New ServerCallBackResult
        Try
            Dim oWebServiceData As WebServiceData = WebServiceData.GetWebServiceData(WebServiceDataJson)
            Dim Dummy As New Dummy(oWebServiceData)
            Try
                Dummy.InsertCountryDetails(Country)
            Catch ex As Exception
                Throw ex
            Finally
                Dummy.Dispose()
            End Try
        Catch ex As Exception
            callBack.Status = EnumStatus.FAIL.ToString
            callBack.ErrorMsg = "DummyWebService::InsertCountryDetails(WebServiceDataJson, Country)    Exception : " + CheckAndGetOleDbExceptionMessage(ex.Message)
            ExceptionLog(callBack.ErrorMsg)
        End Try
    End Sub

End Class
```

Here is the Dummy.vb code:

```
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Imports System.Configuration
Imports System.Web

Public Class Dummy
    Implements IDisposable
    Private oDataInterface As DataInterface
    Private oWebServiceData As WebServiceData

    Protected Overridable Sub Dispose(ByVal disposing As Boolean)
        oDataInterface.Dispose()
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub Finalize()
        MyBase.Finalize()
    End Sub

#Region " IDisposable Support "
    ' This code added by Visual Basic to correctly implement the disposable pattern.
    Public Sub Dispose() Implements IDisposable.Dispose
        ' Do not change this code.  Put cleanup code in Dispose(ByVal disposing As Boolean) above.
        Dispose(True)
        GC.SuppressFinalize(Me)
    End Sub
#End Region

    Public Sub New(ByRef oWebServiceData_in As WebServiceData)
        Try
            Me.oDataInterface = New DataInterface()
            Me.oWebServiceData = oWebServiceData_in
        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw New Exception("Dummy::New() Exception : " + ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub

 Public Sub InsertCountryDetails(ByVal Country As String)
        Try
            oDataInterface.InsertCountryDetails(Country)
        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw New Exception("Dummy::GetColorFromCountryName(Country) Exception : " + ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub

End Class
```

Here is the DataInterface.vb code:

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Imports System.Data

Public Class DataInterface
    Implements IDisposable
    Private oConn As OleDbConnection
    Private disposedValue As Boolean = False
    Private DataFilter As String = String.Empty

    Protected Overridable Sub Dispose(ByVal disposing As Boolean)
        If Not Me.disposedValue Then
            If disposing Then
                CloseConnection()
            End If

        End If
        Me.disposedValue = True
    End Sub

    Private Sub CloseConnection()
        Try
            oConn.Close()
            oConn = Nothing
        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw New Exception("DataInterface::CloseConnection() Exception : " + ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub Finalize()
        MyBase.Finalize()
    End Sub
Public Sub InsertCountryDetails(ByVal Country As String)
        Try
            Dim countryName As String
            countryName = Country
            Dim constring As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=E:\Angular Projects\Dummy\DummyDatabase.accdb"
            Using myconnection As New OleDbConnection(constring)
                myconnection.Open()
                Dim sqlQry As String = "INSERT INTO Countries (Country) VALUES (countryName)"
                Using cmd As New OleDbCommand(sqlQry, myconnection)
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@countryName", countryName)
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                End Using
            End Using
        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw New Exception("DataInterface::GetColor(Country) Exception : " + ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Actually I am a beginner in .NET and Angular and I don't have 100% surety of what I have done is correct or not. So, can anyone please tell me the way of using the http.post() in my case?

Answer (score 0):

I don't do a lot of VB.Net but here are some suggestions on your Angular code

You don't want to get your import from here but from @angular/core
doc is here https://angular.io/api/core/OnInit

if you add private infront of your parameters in your constructor you don't need to assign them, it's an angular shortcut. Docs on that is [here](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4)

app.component.ts

```
import { Component, Inject, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { AppStore } from './app.store';
import { AppState } from './app.state';
import { Store } from 'redux';
import * as DummyService from './Dummy.service';
import * as DummyActions from './Dummy.actions';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

// import { OnInit } from '@angular/core/src/metadata/lifecycle_hooks';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  counter: number;
  country: string;   
  subscription: Subscription;

  constructor( @Inject(AppStore) private store: Store<AppState>, private http$: HttpClient) {


  }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.Load(this.store, this.http$, this.country);
  }

  Load(store: Store<AppState>, http$: HttpClient, country: string) {
    **// you want to unsubscribe to this in the lifecycle hook ngOnDestroy**
    this.subscription = store.subscribe(() => this.readState());
    this.readState();
    DummyService.Load(this.store, this.http$, 'SriLanka');
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

I prefer my services to be injectable, I also don't like to subscribe to my http requests in the service because that means I must unsubscribe to avoid memory leaks so I prefer them to return their results or a promise. Wherever I'm using that service I will subscribe to the promise there so I can be sure to unsubscribe.  Also if your service is injectable it will need to be provided in the module where it intends to be used.  If it's used in multiple modules you might include it in the app module.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import * as Redux from 'redux';
import { HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import * as Model from './app.state';
import * as Actions from './Dummy.actions';
export const PASS = "PASS";
export const FAIL = "FAIL";
export const OMIT = "OMIT";

@Injectable()
export class DummyService {

  constructor(private store: ReducStore<Model.AppState>, private http$: HttpClient) {}

  Load(country: string) {
    try {
        this.http$.get('assets/AppOptions.json',{responseType: "text"}).subscribe(data => {
            try {
                    var oAppOptions:Model.ApplicationOptions = JSON.parse(data);
                    this.store.getState().oApplicationOptions = oAppOptions;
                    InsertCountryDetails(store, http$, country);
            }catch(e) {
                alert("Unable to parse the AppOptions.json file.");
            }
        }, function (error:HttpErrorResponse) {
            alert("An error occured while reading the AppOption file.");
        });
    } catch (e) {
        throw new Error("DummyService::Load() Exception : " + e);
    }
}
InsertCountryDetails(country: string){ 
    var WebServiceDataJson: string = JSON.stringify(this.store.getState().WebServiceData);
    var Servicelink: string = store.getState().oApplicationOptions.WebServiceLink;
    let url = Servicelink + "InsertCountryDetails/" + encodeURI(WebServiceDataJson);
    return this.http$.post(url, country);
}
```

I hope this was helpful.